# drawer not overlapping TWebBrowser Component

Tags: android, c++, user-interface, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I'm developing a web browser with C++Builder 10.0 Seattle that uses a drawer as its master navigation, but the drawer does not overlap the web browser component. I've tried everything but cannot seem to get it working.

[image]

Comment: Your description is too vague. Please explain the exact steps you took to attempt this UI setup. What components are you using? What property settings? What layouts, relationships between components, creation orders, etc? What does the FMX file look like?

Comment: just added the project structure, the navDrawer image is the drawer's master button.thats basically it for now